# Shiny effect on Bootstrap active navbar item via CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have defined a shiny effect via CSS on an active navbar item:

```
@-webkit-keyframes ShineAnimation{
    from {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(
            top left,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 0%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 47%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 49%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 50%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 51%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 53%,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%
        );
        background-position:-250px -250px;
        background-size: 600px 600px
    }
    to {
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:250px 250px;
    }
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a.active {      
    width:100%; /*Make sure the animation is over the whole element*/ 
    -webkit-animation-name: ShineAnimation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

I am using the anchor element as reference because this is how the generated HTML for the navbar item looks as followed:

```
<li class="menu-item"><a href="/kkom/patrick/app.nsf/meetingsUpcoming.xsp" class="active">Kommande agendor</a></li>
```

I have tried to set the active class on the anchor parent element (li) but this does not work since I need to set the width to the element to 100%

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li.active  {      
    width:100%; /*Make sure the animation is over the whole element*/ 
    -webkit-animation-name: ShineAnimation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Using the anchor element is not desired because it is only part of the li element so the shiny effect applies from the half of the li element.

Does anyone has a suggestion how to fix this?

Sample of the HTML for the navbar:

```
<div class="navbar applayout-banner navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="init.xsp">MyApp</a>
    <div class="container-fluid applayout-banner-container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse-target">
                <span class="sr-only">Change Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse-target navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul id="view:_id1:_id2:defLayout_al" class="nav navbar-nav applayout-links">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="/object.xsp?type=Preview" class="active">Running</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="/meetingsUpcoming.xsp" class="inactive">Coming meetings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the markup for your navbar?

Comment: Ofcourse. I have now included it